# Google maps back to original center

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I add google maps on my site

And Allow scrolling.

I want add the option to back to default center, If the user moved away from the original location.

this is my relevan code:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.122150, 34.794246),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
```

Comment: How/When do you want the map to go back to the default center?

Comment: Are you really using the [deprecated and turned off Google Maps Javascript API v2](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-maps-api-2/info)?

Answer (score 0):

You could add an event that resets the center after a set amount of time.

```
map.addListener('center_changed', function() {
    // 3 seconds after the center of the map has changed
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(32.122150, 34.794246))
    }, 3000);
  });
```

Comment: No, I can't do it because maybe the user check how to locate and it may take more than 3 seconds.
I can add my own button on the map to setCenter after click, but I was sure that this option build in on google map.

Comment: Then maybe use the 'idle' event instead of the 'center_changed', so that once the the map is idle for more than a set number of seconds, you can reset the center.

Comment: @24sharon Google doesn't have a "return to center" button as an option.  KMB's solution (or similar) is your best bet.

Comment: The "return to initial center" was removed with the new look/controls, you _might_ be able to get it with the frozen version, but if so, it won't last long.